# A couple of questions about Django

Tags: django

I just got started with **Django** and I would like to ask the more experienced devs some questions about.
One of the main reasons why I chose to swap to Django is the rest-framework API.

Would you say that is good practice to use **djoser** to take care of **auth/register/forgotten passwords** and all other features that the library provide or should I code everything by myself?

If I want to some columns to the user **model** such as **country, location, phone or others** would you recommend me to **override** the default model or create a new model with a one to one relationship linked to the user?

Considering both cases from the question above, will I have to **override** the registration/update methods or is it gonna sort it out by itself?

Answer (score 0):

1st Answer: I haven't used djoser before but i use [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/), it provides all registration and authentication related functionality,its not a good idea to write all the authentication related things on your own,django-rest-auth can save a lot of time

2nd Answer: If all the users are gonna have a country,localtion and other fields then it will be good to extend the default user model.

Bonus: Checkout the [django cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it provides boilerplate for a django project and save developers time.

Comment: If you want to learn how authentication and registration function works,then in order to learn you can write the auth functionality on your own.